# AVG or SUM in SQL where the values are being calculated on the fly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing SQL query that gets call stats from a Zultys MX250 phone system: -

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(u.firstname,1),LEFT(u.lastname,1)) AS Name,
    sec_to_time(SUM(
        time_to_sec(s.disconnecttimestamp) - time_to_sec(s.connecttimestamp)
    )) AS Duration,
    COUNT(*) AS '#Calls'
FROM
    session s
    JOIN mxuser u ON
        s.ExtensionID1 = u.ExtensionId
        OR s.ExtensionID2 = u.ExtensionId
WHERE
    s.ServiceExtension1 IS NULL
    AND s.connecttimestamp >= CURRENT_DATE
    AND BINARY u.userprofilename = BINARY 'DBAM'
GROUP BY
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname
ORDER BY
    '#Calls' DESC,
    Duration DESC;
```

Output is as follows: -

```
Name    Duration        #Calls
TH      01:19:10        30
AS      00:44:59        28
EW      00:51:13        22
SH      00:21:20        13
MG      00:12:04        8
TS      00:42:02        5
DS      00:00:12        1
```

I am trying to generate a 4th column that shows the average call time for each user, but am struggling to figure out how.

Mathematically it's just "'Duration' / '#Calls'" but after looking at some similar questions on StackOverflow, the example queries are too simple to help me relate to my one above.

Right now, I'm not even sure that it's going to be possible to divide the time column by the number of calls.

**UPDATE**: I was so close in my testing but got all confused & overcomplicated things.  Here's the latest SQL (thanks to @McAdam331 & my buddy Jim from work): -

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(u.firstname,1),LEFT(u.lastname,1)) AS Name,
    sec_to_time(SUM(
        time_to_sec(s.disconnecttimestamp) - time_to_sec(s.connecttimestamp)
    )) AS Duration,
    COUNT(*) AS '#Calls',
    sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(s.disconnecttimestamp) - time_to_sec(s.connecttimestamp)) / COUNT(*)) AS Average
FROM
    session s
    JOIN mxuser u ON
        s.ExtensionID1 = u.ExtensionId
        OR s.ExtensionID2 = u.ExtensionId
WHERE
    s.ServiceExtension1 IS NULL
    AND s.connecttimestamp >= CURRENT_DATE
    AND BINARY u.userprofilename = BINARY 'DBAM'
GROUP BY
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname
ORDER BY
    Average DESC;
```

Output is as follows: -

```
Name    Duration        #Calls  Average
DS      00:14:25        4       00:03:36
MG      00:17:23        11      00:01:34
TS      00:33:38        22      00:01:31
EW      01:04:31        43      00:01:30
AS      00:49:23        33      00:01:29
TH      00:43:57        35      00:01:15
SH      00:13:51        12      00:01:09
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are able to get the number of total seconds, as you do before converting it to time. Why not take the number of total seconds, divide that by the number of calls, and then convert that back to time?

```
SELECT sec_to_time(
   SUM(time_to_sec(s.disconnecttimestamp) - time_to_sec(s.connecttimestamp)) / COUNT(*)) 
   AS averageDuration
```

Comment: Or use `SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.connecttimestamp, s.disconnecttimestamp))`

Comment: Thanks McAdam331 - I tried upvoting your answer, but I am 14 points shy of being able to!

Comment: @furriephillips No need to apologize. If this is the answer that helps you, you can always accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just replace `sum()` with `avg()`:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(u.firstname,1),LEFT(u.lastname,1)) AS Name,
    sec_to_time(SUM(
        time_to_sec(s.disconnecttimestamp) - time_to_sec(s.connecttimestamp)
    )) AS Duration,
    COUNT(*) AS `#Calls`,
    sec_to_time(AVG(
        time_to_sec(s.disconnecttimestamp) - time_to_sec(s.connecttimestamp)
    )) AS AvgDuration
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need is another expression in the SELECT list. The `SUM()` aggregate (from the second expression) divided by `COUNT` aggregate (the third expr). Then wrap that in a `sec_to_time` function. (Unless I'm totally missing the question.)

Personally, I'd use the TIMESTAMPDIFF function to get a difference in times.

```
SEC_TO_TIME(
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,s.connecttimestamp,s.disconnecttimestamp))
  / COUNT(*)
) AS avg_duration
```

If what you are asking is there's a way to reference other expressions in the SELECT list by the alias... the answer is unfortunately, there's not.

With a performance penalty, you could use your existing query as an inline view, then in the outer query, the alias names assigned to the expressions are available...

```
SELECT t.Name
     , SEC_TO_TIME(s.TotalDur) AS Duration
     , s.`#Calls`
     , SEC_TO_TIME(s.TotalDur/s.`#Calls`) AS avgDuration
  FROM (
         SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(u.firstname,1),LEFT(u.lastname,1)) AS Name
              , SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,s.connecttimestamp,s.disconnecttimestamp)) AS TotalDur
              , COUNT(1) AS `#Calls`
           FROM session s 
               -- the rest of your query
       ) t
```